# Magento2 - Plugin on ShippingMethodConverter not working

Tags: magento2, plugin

Class overwrites should be a last resort option when customising M2. I personally stick by the following order: plugin -> observer -> class rewrite.

I am having an issue in the \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter area. I'm trying to write a before plugin but for some reason it doesn't work.

I have the following code:
frontend/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter">
    <plugin name="Namespace\Quote\Plugin\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter" type="Namespace\Quote\Plugin\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter" sortOrder="1" />
</type>
```

Namespace\Quote\Plugin\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter.php

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Quote\Plugin\Quote\Model\Cart;

class ShippingMethodConverter
{
    public function beforeModelToDataObject($subject, $result, $rate, $quote)
    {
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Any idea why this is happening I want to avoid class overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

Found what the issue was. The di.xml should have been in etc/di.xml not etc/frontend/di.xml.